# Can we stream data from ADX to Databricks Spark cluster?

Tags: spark-streaming, azure-data-explorer

Does ADX support sending data to Databricks Spark cluster in streaming fashion -- basically Spark will pull it from ADX instead of ADX exporting it? In other words, I am trying to understand if an ADX table can act as a source for spark streaming ? Is there an example link for this that I can go through?

Comment: ADX Spark connector does not support read stream out of the box, please look at Ziv Caspi in order to achieve that along with creating a custom stream provider. Might help you -  https://fdeantoni.medium.com/custom-spark-structured-streaming-datasource-with-websockets-3313dc53b811

Answer (score 2):

ADX provides the means for querying a table for all the data that has been added to it since the last query through the means of [Database Cursors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/databasecursor). Note, however, that this requires the caller to parse the query's @ExtendedProperties set (which holds the database cursor) and maintain state between every two successive queries (so that the new cursor value could be passed to the next query).

Comment: So logically it's the same thing that continuous export is doing , so performance wise it will be similar to continuous export isn't it?

Comment: Also, in that case it doesn't really sound like it's streaming, it's just like querying and exporting out of ADX. So can we say that ADX doesn't support streaming data out of it , the way it supports streaming ingestion ?